# How to get value from json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is the json encoded string using php :

```
{"customer_id":"1","customer_name":"dd"}
```

I want to fetch the value `customer_name` from above string:

My code:

```
var obj=json.parse(data);
  $.each(obj,function(item){
     item.customer_name                 
  });
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `$.each`. Just call `obj.customer_name` after you parse the JSON. You only need `$.each` if your data is an array.

Answer (score 1):

object.key will give you the value.

```
obj = {"customer_id":"1","customer_name":"dd"};
obj.customer_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all data using `obj.` like `obj.customer_name` try

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
alert(obj.customer_name);
```

Comment: You shouldn't create JSON in PHP using literals, you should use `json_encode`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the job

```
var obj=JSON.parse(data);
alert(obj.customer_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON suppose to be an array of objects

Make your JSON look like this:

```
var obj = [{customer_id:"1",customer_name:"dd"}];
```

Then iterate like this using `jquery`

```
var obj = [{customer_id:"1",customer_name:"dd"}];

$.each(obj,function(key,val){
     console.log(val.customer_name);                 
  });
```